# Updating NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS table value permanently

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

I want to update for all fields of `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS` table permanently. I have tried update operation, but getting below error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02030: can only select from fixed tables/views
02030. 00000 -  "can only select from fixed tables/views"
*Cause:    An attempt is being made to perform an operation other than
           a retrieval from a fixed table/view.
*Action:   You may only select rows from fixed tables/views.
```

Can anyone help me to understand how to change/update the parameter value for `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS` table.

Comment: Well, the whole point of session parameters is to have parameters that are only valid for current session. Do you want to change system-wide parameters, or to set some session parameters automatically for a given program?

Comment: You should never even attempt to directly update internal tables. Anyway, this view (not table) shows the current settings for the current session. Some of those are based on your external environment (e.g. via `$NLS_LANG`) - so there is nothing to permanently change. It reflects `alter session` changes too. (You can change `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS` permanently via appropriate DBA `alter` commands, but that's a separate issue really.) What do you want to set, who for (one user? all users?), and why?

Comment: Set `NLS_LANG` environment variable https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/setting-up-globalization-support-environment.html#GUID-6475CA50-6476-4559-AD87-35D431276B20

Comment: Hi @astentx, 
Could you please help me to understand how and where to set NLS_LANG environment variable

Comment: Also please describe what you want to achieve, since NLS are about data representation and implicit type casts: while the former has nothing to do with the original data (`01.01.2023` is the same as `01/01/2023` and `2023-01-01` - they are the same point in time) the latter should be avoided to make things clear and explicit.

Comment: @astentx,
I want to adapt Belgium territory format in my current database permanently.  Currently my NLS_TERRITORY is America

Comment: `$ setenv NLS_LANG=BELGUIM_GERMAN.AL32UTF8` in unix, `ps> [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('NLS_LANG','BELGUIM_GERMAN.AL32UTF8', 'User')` for windows

Comment: Have a read through [Oracle 12.2: Setting up a globalization support environment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/setting-up-globalization-support-environment.html)

Answer (score 3):

1. `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS` is a dictionary view. All dictionary views and tables are to be managed through DDL (`CREATE, ALTER, DROP`, etc..) never through your own manual inserts/updates/deletes.
2. Any parameter you can change with `ALTER SESSION` you can also change with `ALTER SYSTEM` which makes it so for all users of the database and so will remain across your connections, but that's something only a DBA can do. To make it permanent across database instance restarts, though, you'd have to either put it in the initialization file (`$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/init$SID.ora`) or if an SPFILE is in use, add "`scope=BOTH`" or "`scope=SPFILE`" to the `ALTER SYSTEM` command. Again, this is only for DBAs.
3. If you can't change it at the instance level with `ALTER SYSTEM`, then you have a few choices:

   3.1 Do the `ALTER SESSION` upon *every connection you make*

   3.2 Create a *private logon trigger* that does the `ALTER SESSION`s for you

   3.3 Call a *procedure* upon logon that does the `ALTER SESSION`s for you

   3.4 Lastly, if all you want to do is change your language territory and/or characterset, you can set the *host environment variable* `NLS_LANG` on your operating system. Your client will inherit these values and set `NLS_LANGUAGE` for you. Several other NLS parameters can be set this way. see the documentation on "*Setting up an NLS environment*"

Answer (score 0):

You can only alter session set parameter=value. And that is not permanent, but only for that database session and will not affect other database sessions. Maybe you should use a script or stored procedure to set the parameters as needed immediately after connecting to the database.
See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ALTER-SESSION.html